# How to Automate Radio Button in iOS Application using Appium?

Tags: java, ios, radio-button, appium

There is a requirement in my application, where i need to select any one of the photo from native app and then click on delete button. But i am not able to select any particular photo.
I followed following steps :

1. I created an list which will check if there are photos present or
   not?
2. If the photos are present, then i will click on any particular
       photo.
3. And then click on delete button.

But my code does not select the photo, even if the element is displayed.

Following way i have located the elements:

```
@iOSFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeImage[contains(@name,'tick-1.png')]")
private MobileElement selectPhoto;
@iOSFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeImage[contains(@name,'tick-1.png')]")
private List<MobileElement> listOfPhotos;
```

And when i do,

```
listOfPhotos.isEmpty()
```

which returns false, and which is expected as there is one photo present.

But when i click on element,

```
selectPhoto.click
```

it does not select the photo.

However, `selectPhoto.isDisplayed` returns true.

So, can anyone tell me how to automate it?